# How to swap SPL token using Raydium Liquidity Pool V4

Tags: web3.js, spl-token-program

Please let me know how to swap SPL token using Raydium Liquidity Pool V4.
I need sample code.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/0xcrust/raydium-swap) is a project I made to do this in Rust. Note that I haven’t actually tested it yet so use at your own discretion!

It should be useful as a reference point though.

Comment: How can I connect you? Email or Telegram or Discord something like that. Can you teach me? Now I am testing your answer but Rust is first for me. Seems too late.

Comment: Too late for what? I can give you a few pointers on twitter but I can't promise much time. The handle's @crust0x.

Please consider asking your questions here first as it's a public forum that others can view, contribute and learn from

Comment: OK, I see. I would like to discuss this code execution using anydesk. Thank you.